# In ExtJS what would the opposite of lazy instantiation be called?

Tags: extjs

I have no idea what to call a "non-lazy" instantiation of objects in ExtJS...  Could it be called standard instantiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite term for lazy initialization is **eager initialization**.

Eager initialization is essentially computing the tasks when you ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

Eager Instantiation is used in loading data into tabs.  An application which has tab panel will load the tab if and when the user clicks on the tab. At this point it is advisable to use eager initialization in loading the tabs.